# Express : render array and update when array change

Tags: node.js, express, ejs, setinterval

i have a little problem here, i have an array which is changing automatically each 30 seconds, and i want to render this array to my ejs file and update the data when the array changes
here is the code :

```
const request = require("request");
const cheerio = require("cheerio");
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");

const app = express();
app.use(express.json()); // req.body
app.use(cors());
app.set("view engine", "ejs");

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  let titles = [];

  setInterval(() => {
    request("SOMEWEBSITE",(error, response, html) => {
        const $ = cheerio.load(html);

        $(".aditem").each((i, el) => {
          let title = $(el).find(".class").text();

          titles.push(title);
        });
      }
    );
  }, 5000);
  res.render("index", { titles });
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("3000");
});
```

when i am logging titles, it's changing but it's not rendering to my ejs file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only get to send ONE http response to the incoming request so you can only call res.render() once per http request.

Possible solutions are:

1. Polling. Have Javascript in the web page ask your server for updated data every so often via an Ajax call.
2. Have your page do an automatic page refresh causing it to automatically reload every so often and thus display a fresh version of the page.
3. Make a webSocket or socket.io connection from the web page to the server so the server can then send new data to the web page whenever it is available over the webSocket or socket.io connection. The Javascript in the web page will then receive that data and it can insert it into the current page.